# How to display selected value in drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display the selected name in the drop down list,
this is my view code

```
<tr data-view-key="<?php echo $jmf_id; ?>">
<td class="jnl_id"><?php echo $jmf_jnl_id; ?></td>
<td class="question"><?php echo $jmf_question; ?></td> 
<td class="question_type">
    <?php 
    if($jmf_question_type == 'ss')
    {
    echo 'Single select (checkbox)';
    }
    else if($jmf_question_type == 'ms')
    {
    echo 'Multi select (checkbox)';
    }
    else if($jmf_question_type == 'mo')
    {
    echo 'Multi option (radio)';
    }
    else if($jmf_question_type == 'ft')
    {
    echo 'Free textarea';
    }
    ?>
</td>
<td class="question_option"><?php echo $jmf_question_options; ?></td>
<td>
    <a href="#<?php echo $jmf_id; ?>" name="edit_meta" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#<?php echo $jmf_id; ?>" name="delete_meta" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a>
</td>
```

Jquery code is

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name = 'edit_meta']", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
        $("a[name='delete_meta']").confirmation("hide");
        var jmf_id = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
        var parent = $(this).parents("[data-view-key='"+jmf_id+"']");
        var jnl_id = parent.find("td.jnl_id").text();
        var question = parent.find("td.question").text();
        var question_type = parent.find("td.question_type").text();//output eg: Multi select (checkbox)
        var question_option = parent.find("td.question_option").text();
        $("#hdn_mf_id").val(jmf_id);
        $("#question").val(question);
       --> $("#question_type").val(question_type);//want to display the selected list item here(not value).

        $("#question_options").val(question_option);


});
```

i want to display the listed item name in the drop down list,what function can use instead of `.val()`

Comment: Why don't you give a try `$(element).val()` ?

Comment: @Vineet I want to show the selected name in the drop down list on .onclick function,in following line var question_type = parent.find("td.question_type").text();//output eg: Multi select (checkbox) i got the value,but how to assign this to the drop down list (whose id="question_options"), Multi select (checkbox) is not the value for this 'ms' is the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the selected option using `:selected` target and get it's attribute 'name'

```
$("#question_type option:selected").attr('name')
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1240/

If you wish to the display the selected text from the dropdown

```
$("#question_type option:selected").text()
```

example ; http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3kgbG/1241/

Comment: var question_type = parent.find("td.question_type").text();//console.log(question_type)-output eg: Multi select (checkbox),using $("#question_type option:selected").text(question_type),I displayed this in drop down list,but when submit the data the value doesn't pass.

Comment: In order to post data from a form, each element needs to have the name attribute. In your case, you are probably missing that. Your drop down should be like : <select name="questionType" id="question_type">